# Ansible builtin template unable to create valid yaml result with integer values

Tags: integer, jinja2, ansible-template

I want to template `.yaml` files with ansible. This is a standard job, I assumed, but then I realized that the template module is unable to produce valid integers in the YAML output.

Given an inventory var `bar` is set to `1`, using the following template:

```yaml
foo: "{{ bar | int }}"
```

and a very basic playbook, just doing the template. Doing so, I end up with

```yaml
foo: "1"
```

in the resulting .yaml file which is wrong. According to the docs, the result should be

```yaml
foo: 1
```

I am using ansible `2.10.5`

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized, that I have to treat a template as what it is: a template.

I worked around this by writing a test that fills the template and lints the result. This is a little more work, but ensures valid template results.

Answer (score 0):

At your `.j2` template, you don't need to quote your expression.

> These quotes are part of your template and will be part of the rendered output.
>
> ...
>
> Everything that is not inside a jinja2 delimited block ({%, {{, etc.) will translate to the rendered value.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61685601/6346520

So you can write:

```
foo: {{ bar }}
```